# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, information-retrieval

I'm trying to get value from one to one relation. My models are Users and Vehicles. One user can have muliple vehicles but one vehicles can have only one user. I'm getting error in my view:

> invalid argument in foreach() in my view.

Following is my syntax. Can any one help me?

```
//users:
class users extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['fname','lname','address','contact','shop_name','email','username','password'];
    public function vehicles() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\vehicles');
    }
}

//vehicles:
class vehicles extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['vname','lotno','engine','mileage','kilometers','features','price','negotiable','vcondition','used','manufacture_year','description','Company_cid','Sellers_sid','Vehicle_Type_id'];    
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\users');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $vehicles=vehicles::findorfail($id);
    return view('Bike.show',compact('vehicles'));
}
```

View where I'm trying to get value of user.

```
<tr>
<td><b>Contact No:</b></td>
 <td>                               
   @foreach($vehicles->users as $users)
    {{$users->contact}}
   @endforeach
</td>
</tr>
```

I don't know where i did wrong. It shows an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: Is `$vehicles` successfully set at all?  In your controller, just `return $vehicles;`, what do you get?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It is returning all required values.

Answer (score 3):

`foreach()` requires an argument to be a collection or array. Since a Vehicle belongsTo only one user, `$vehicles->users` won't give a collection. You don't really require a foreach loop there. `$vehicle->users->contact` will do.

Note: If One user can have multiple vehicles, the relation should instead be:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Vehicle');
```

Also note the naming conventions: Model name to be singular, if it is hasOne relation always make the relation singular e.g `user()` not `users()` and if it is hasMany make it plural.

Comment: `dd($vehicles) ` to see what it gives

Comment: `vehicles {#190 ▼
  #fillable: array:15 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:17 [▶]
  #original: array:17 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}`

Comment: `@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
    {{$vehicle->users->contact}}
   @endforeach` but i wonder  `$vehicles=vehicles::findorfail($id);` giving a collection.

Comment: Still the same. When i tried returning $vehicles->users in controller.It showed empty. I wonder if it is causing the problem.